# How to create a SUM IF BOLD formula in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sumifs

I want to create a formula, that combines the SUM IF (SUMMEWENN) and a SUMBOLD (SUMMEFETT) functions.

I already found a SUMBOLD formula from [here](https://administrator.de/forum/summe-bilden-wenn-zahlen-fett-89661.html) but I don't know how to create the SUMIFBOLD (SUMMEWENNFETT) formula, can anyone tell me the vba-code?
Thank you.

Comment: The code you point at has an if statement: `If IsNumeric(Zelle.Value) Then Summe = Summe + Zelle.Value` so all you need to do is add and conditions to it.

Comment: What is not working with code you point at? How have you tried to modify it? And what's your condition for SUM IF?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function:

```
Function SumIfBold(rng_crit As Range, rng_sum As Range) As Double
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim i As Long

    Total = 0 ' Initialize the total to zero

    ' Check if both ranges have the same number of cells
    If rng_crit.Cells.Count <> rng_sum.Cells.Count Then
        SumIfBold = 0 ' Return 0 if the ranges don't match
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 1 To rng_crit.Cells.Count
        If rng_crit.Cells(i).Font.Bold = True Then
            Total = Total + rng_sum.Cells(i).Value
        End If
    Next i

    SumIfBold = Total ' Return the total
End Function
```